# set up $DISPLAY VARIABLE

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

While trying to use the python turtle module to write a program I came across an issue. I have turtle installed but after I ran the code below for testing purposes:

```
import turtle
import random

turtle = turtle.Turtle()
```

I came across this error in the terminal. There have been similar questions on stackoverflow but those pertained to matplotlib which was also having the same error and the answers for the matplotlib error could not be applied to turtle. Below is the error in the terminal.
File "", line 1, in 
  File

```
"/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 3702, in __init__
    Turtle._screen = Screen()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 3552, in Screen
    Turtle._screen = _Screen()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 3568, in __init__
    _Screen._root = self._root = _Root()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/turtle.py", line 458, in __init__
    TK.Tk.__init__(self)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1814, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

My question is how do I set up an environment $DISPLAY variable. I have also made sure that I have tkinter intstalled. This is a mac computer with python 2.7.

Comment: It just so happens that i do know what X11, OSX, and python/tkinter are. You do not have to come on here acting like you are better than other people, especially by making a wise comment that gives no answer what so ever. Stackoverflow is intended to help programmers not discourage and bash them.

Comment: Whoa! Chill out. Most people who use OSX don't know what X11 is, and those that do typically know about how to set DISPLAY properly. I asked  the question because I can think of two or three solutions to your problem, but the correct solution depends on the answer to my question. <shrug>

Comment: Okay, I understand now, but if you have a solution please post it below, because right now I am using a VM for turtle, and I do not like it as much as natively. I am using version 8.6 for TKinter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

their is no module name Turtle()

instead of using Turtle use turtle python is a case sensitive language so please make sure that you are using right case of alphabets

turtle = turtle.turtle()

if you find any such error first tried it in python shell you will definately get it corrected.

Comment: This did not wok unfortunately. The error is "there is no module named turtle. Also I want to thank you for trying to help but turtle is a module and Turtle() creates an instance of an object type turtle. It is a class, that is why it is capitalized. turlte.Turtle() initiates a type of turtle. I did this in my VM and if worked fine, I just can not seem to get it to work natively.

Comment: This has nothing to do with setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

Comment: The error was that I need to set us a $DISPLAY Variable.

Comment: i use turtle a long time ago but i never encounter such error and i used it in windows 7. open your python IDLE and then press f1 it open a chm file then search for turtle you will definitely find the solution.